# Android Web Request Timing Problems

Tags: android

I'm building an application which needs some data from server. I know how to check internet connection using **ConnectivityManager**, but i'm wondering (it only checks whether some WIFI is connected to the device or not)

> What if internet connection is available but no internet access( not able to browse the web)
>
> What if internet connection is too slow( i can tell the users to wait)
>
> What if server is too slow in responding

Please respond with your precious suggestions.
Thanks

Comment: thanks for down-voting without any suggestions it really helped me a lot :/

Answer (score 1):

- For WiFi link speed check [WifiInfo.getLinkSpeed()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiInfo.html#getLinkSpeed%28%29)
- For Mobile Data Link you can only check [TelefonyManager.getNetworkType()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#getNetworkType%28%29) to determine the current Mobile Data Link type. You should then aproximate to actual speed by link type (i.e. for GPRS up to 128 kbps, for EDGE up to 236.8 kpbs, for 3G up to 2 Mbps, for HDSPA up to 7.2 Mbps). Take into consideration that this is only an aproximation. Your could be conneting using HDSPA but your carrier limiting the top speed to 2 Mbps.

Now , you have to get speed and put condition whether below 10kbps , "slow internet connection"

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15704141/slow-internet-connection-issue-in-android#answer-15704273)

Comment: Well this is one way to check, another way is check the time taken to retrieve a request from server/or load a page in your webview, if it exceeds a given time span toast or show a message showing net is slow or whatever error needs to be shown

Comment: well this is what i was wondering, what if the server takes forever to respond, we cannot ask the users to wait and wait, they will eventually leave

Comment: for that u have to put timeout and if the time exceeds timeout tell thm something ....

Comment: hmmm, hope it helps you out. if it has answered your query do mark it as answered. Thanks